# Only can select one contact, how to get multi selection using ContactUI?

Tags: ios, swift

DESIRED: I'm trying to be able to select multiple contacts in ContactsUI like this: [image: How I want it (dont mind blue boxes)]

CURRENT: I cant find a way to get the multiple selection buttons in the table view cells[image: How it looks, only single selection]

As you can see from the code belowI'm using the contactPickerView so I dont know what I'm doing wrong :/

```
import UIKit
import ContactsUI
import Contacts


class FindContactsVC: UIViewController, CNContactPickerDelegate {

    //button to open contactUI
    @IBAction func contactsButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let cnPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
        cnPicker.delegate = self    
        self.present(cnPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)  
    }

    //Works, but only allows me to select one at a time
    func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact) {
        print(contact.phoneNumbers)
        print("WYASDFY")
    }

    //This function never runs :/
    func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContacts contacts: [CNContact]){
       print(contacts)
        print("plz work!")
        contacts.forEach { contact in
            for number in contact.phoneNumbers {
                let phoneNumber = number.value 
                print("number is = \(phoneNumber)")
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()       
    }
}
```

Thanks ^.^

Comment: Do you fixed this problem???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't checked other parts of your code, but at least, you need to implement the second delegate method properly:

```
func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContacts contacts: [CNContact]){
```

↓

```
func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contacts: [CNContact]) {
```

Comment: Never said thank you, this worked like a charm. I got the code from a tutorial. I'm curious why argument labels are a thing / can break your code so easily without error messages. I never see the labels (didSelect) used, only the second part (contacts) @OOPer

Comment: @Wikkle_A, Swift is changing so rapid, and Swift 3 has drastically changed how to import old APIs. Your second method was valid in Swift 2. If you could not have found warnings with it, you should send a Bug Report to Apple. And better find a tutorial which is explicitly marked as "for Swift 3", when you write some code with Swift 3/Xcode 8.